# How to combine short term and long term time series?

Tags: time-series, midas

I need to combine two traffic data series which are long term ( with 15 S / 30 S/1 minute interval) and short term( with 2 S/ 3 s) for my research purpose. These two types of data series reflect different traffic dynamics.

What would be the best way to do it/ what would be the most suitable technique?

Comment: Why do the series need to be combined at all?

Answer (score 7):

Try the MIDAS (mixed data sampling) approach. It is intended for situations such as yours.

Software implementation is available in `R` (package `midasr`), `Matlab` ([users guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20170517043931/http://www.unc.edu/%7Eeghysels/papers/MIDAS_Usersguide_Version8.pdf)) and perhaps other statistical packages.